# Run PHP 24hrs After Event Trigger

Tags: php

I'm a bit lost on this one and would appreciate some direction. I have created a plugin that sends a message to a user after they successfully sign up. However, I would like this message to be sent 24 hours after the event is triggered (their account verification).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In below function take the registration date of the user and add 24 hours to the registration date. If current time matches the $notify time then send message.

```
$notify = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+24 hours",strtotime($registration_date)));
if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")==$notify){
    //send message code
}
```

Comment: And where should this code go? How is it executed? Will it calculate the time diff for every user on every request?

Comment: You can use wp cronjob to run this code automatically in functions.php. This might help you somehow https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/

Comment: Can you edit your information to contain this info? And if you use a scheduled event, is there even the need to calculate `$notify` anymore?

Comment: You just need to pass the user's registration date and inside the if condition write the code to send message. It will automatically calculate the notify time and if matched it will send the message (if there is no error in your message sending code

Comment: You need to calculate the notify time in order to send the message after 24 hours of registration. If there is a user who registered 1st April 9:00 AM then he would receive the message on 2nd April 9:00 AM and if there is a user who registered 1st April 9:00 PM then he would receive the message on 2nd April 9:00 PM

Comment: I understand all of this, as your answer (without the comments) stands right now, I believe it is unclear to the OP what really has to be done. And if you schedule the event for now + 24h to run, you don't need to calculate the time anymore because your event was scheduled to run at that point.

Comment: No if he schedule a cronjob to be executed after 24 hours then if there is a user that registered 2 mins prior to the cronjob schedule, will receive a message after 2 mins of registration. As it is clearly mentioned that the user would receive message after 24 hours of registration.